# Is google docs made by microsoft?

Tags: office365, web, google-docs

Is google docs made by microsoft?

They launched a few months ago office online (office 365) so why would they if they were already maintaining google docs.

But someone told me it was them (who were doing google docs?) so I don't know what to think.

Edit: I couldn't find anything saying it was maintained by microsoft, so I guess it's not. But then, why do they have the same icons?

Comment: No. Till now, Google is Google and Microsoft is Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks, this is really of good help. The question was if Google docs was maintained by microsoft.

Comment: @MarcheRemi - No; The service is ran by Google, which is the reason, its called *Google Docs*

Comment: Further, Office265 has been around for 6 years, not "a few months ago", and the two services do NOT use the same icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: No. Google is Google and Microsoft is Microsoft.
Your second question: "Why do they have the same icon"
Office 365 is cloud based, you can store your documents in "The Cloud," just like Google Docs, or One Drive, etc.
So, it has a similar functionality in that respect.
Hopefully, those are the answers you were looking for.